# Why get broken pipe error inside a screen?

Tags: bash, command-line

I start using screen to be able to scp folder from my laptop to a server without getting 'broken pipe: connection lost' error. And it had worked fine until now. Today, I re-attached to a screen and the broken pipe error was there.

How is this possible and how to prevent it?

Best wishes

Comment: That's really much too vague to be answerable -- any kind of connection drop (network failures nothing to do with screen) could cause your error, but so could a session key renegotiation that requires access to a SSH agent that goes away when you detach from the screen session. Also, keep in mind that [StackOverflow's scope](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is limited to problems "*unique* to software development"; people who aren't programmers use `scp` and `screen`. When you have a version of this question with enough details to be answerable, [unix.se] might be a better forum.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do what you suggested.

Comment: Try using the `-vv` arguments to `scp` to enable very verbose logging -- that way the contents you have in your screen session after reattaching have a higher likelihood of being useful (if it *is* something more than a random network drop). And good luck!